# Can Substitution Rule for Equality be rewritten this way?

Tags: logic

p68 of Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic says

> 4.4 Substitution Rule for Equality
>
> $$\frac{\Gamma \quad \vdash \quad \phi\frac{t}{x}}{\Gamma \quad t
>  \equiv t' \quad \vdash \quad \phi\frac{t'}{x}}$$

Can it be rewritten as:

$$\begin{align*} 
\Gamma \quad \vdash \quad \phi\frac{t}{x} \\
\Gamma \quad \vdash \quad t \equiv t'\\
\hline \\
\Gamma \quad \vdash \quad \phi\frac{t'}{x} \\
\end{align*}$$

?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, see e.g. Franco Parlamento & Flavio Previale, [Absorbing the structural rules in the sequent calculus with additional atomic rules (2019)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11407) for different approaches to equality rules.